# unsupervised outliers detection - possible solution?

Tags: anomaly-detection, outlier

I have dataset of traders' transaction data: trade id, date, stock id, sector of stock id, buy-or-sell, volume $

The goal is to identify anomalies in transactions data of traders. For example to find suspicious transactions.

As I dont have information how real outliers look like so it is unsupervised algorithms.
As usual unsupervised algorithms I tried k-mean, z-score, lot, one class svm and different things with moving average etc.

Ive got results, but I was able to use only volume and date for every trader.

Is there any algorithm that can help me to include sector data/stock data/buy-sell data to do my model better? Can I include this information in above unsupervised algorithms or Im missing something?

How would you tackle this task, are there any other solutions maybe?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: If you have prior labelled data, where labelled are based upon inlier vs outlier, in such case you develop anomaly detection models. Like outliers or novelty detection. Scikit have good explanation for these.

Comment: When using z score, it should be done within its group (same product.. Seller?) also.. If your data is presented in time dimension, you should consider residual (changes on time step to avoid growing - collapsing behavior)

Comment: Once I played around Autoencoders on Normal Bank Transactions, and it worked quite OK. But it was on a benchmark dataset, not a real world dataset. Still you can try Autoencoders or Variational Autoencoders. The problem is, if you literally have no data or idea what anomalies in transactions data of traders look like, it is hard to evaluate any unsupervised algorithms. Maybe it is best to think about labeling small part of your data for testing, if not available for training!

Comment: @vipin bansal I tied, here is good link for it https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/outlier_detection.html. But those models only use volume and datetime data. How can I add sector/stock/buy-sell data? Or you meant something else?

Comment: @krayyem could you please send a link with a good explatation about it?

Comment: @TwinPenguins could like this https://www.datascience.com/blog/fraud-detection-with-tensorflow? Still it uses numeral data. Maybe you know how can I transpose sector/stock/buy-sell to numbers? Because I cant just turn it to random numbers - one sector per number, because if we use algorithm that counts distance between 2 points, "random number" realy make no sence

Comment: Link is correct. Both algo's Novelty and Outlier Detection, trained a model like any other ML model. You just have to pass your training data. In your case, training data will have features like, sector, stock, buy-sell etc.

Comment: @vipin bansal but if I have sector like "bank" and stock like "Volkswagen" how can i transpose it to numbers? or I can use strings?

Comment: My bad. Your data must be numerical for model consumption. Scikit provides you many handy methods for data pre-processing. In your case you need label encoding, https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.LabelEncoder.html.

Comment: @ vipin bansal thanks. But almost all unsupervised algorithms count smallest distance between points, so if we code sector A as 1 and sector X as 1000, that will be huge difference and look not like random recoding or not?

Comment: Yes, like the link you sent. Sure you should convert your categoricals in a meaningful way to numerical values first. There is another method though, called Entity Encoding, that enables you to feed your categorical variables in a embedding fashion to a neural network and learn the embedding matrix (weights) on the fly during training. Maybe you can combine this logic together with autoencoders. I have actually written a notebook about Entity Encoding (https://github.com/mmortazavi/EntityEmbedding-Working_Example), but not combined with Autoeconder (this is a part you can easily do!).